# powershell, csv-date imported in different formate

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, date, import

I want to import this kind of csv into Excel

Work Item Type,ID,State,Date Request,Created Date
"Task","4533","Closed","2-9-2020 14:26:00","3-9-2020 08:17:39"
"Task","4535","Closed","3-9-2020 12:26:44","3-9-2020 12:29:33"
"Task","4577","Closed","3-9-2020 15:56:00","4-9-2020 09:12:21"
"Task","4580","New","17-8-2020 09:47:00","4-9-2020 09:49:39"
"Task","4581","Resolved","28-8-2020 10:22:00","4-9-2020 10:24:46"
"Task","4582","Resolved","24-8-2020 10:05:00","4-9-2020 10:31:12"
"Task","4604","Resolved","8-9-2020 08:06:58","8-9-2020 08:07:23"
"Task","4605","Resolved","8-9-2020 09:18:32","8-9-2020 09:18:58"

All dates in this example must be seen with a format day-month-year hour:minute:second

I do the import like this:

```
    Import-Csv -Path '.\Issues.csv' | ForEach-Object {

    $sheet1.Cells.Item(1,1) = 'ID'
    $sheet1.Cells.Item(1,2) = 'Status'
    $sheet1.Cells.Item(1,3) = 'Date Request'
    $sheet1.Cells.Item(1,4) = 'Date Created'

    $DateRequest = ([datetime]::ParseExact(($($_."Date Request")),$fmtDate,$inv).ToString($fmtDate))

    $sheet1.Cells.Item($row,1) = $($_.ID)
    $sheet1.Cells.Item($row,2) = $($_.State)
    $sheet1.Cells.Item($row,3) = $($_."Date Request")
    $sheet1.Cells.Item($row,4) = $($_."Created Date")

    $row = $row + 1

}
```

The result of my Import

```
ID      Status      Date Request          Date Created
4533    Closed      9/02/2020 14:26       9/03/2020 8:17
4535    Closed      9/03/2020 12:26       9/03/2020 12:29
4577    Closed      9/03/2020 15:56       9/04/2020 9:12
4580    New         17-8-2020 09:47:00    9/04/2020 9:49
4581    Resolved    28-8-2020 10:22:00    9/04/2020 10:24
4582    Resolved    24-8-2020 10:05:00    9/04/2020 10:31
4604    Resolved    9/08/2020 8:06        9/08/2020 8:07
4605    Resolved    9/08/2020 9:18        9/08/2020 9:18
```

**As you can see, some dates are red in the CSV with a month-day-year format,
other are red with a day-month-year format.
The date 3 september has become 9 march**

I have tried using CultureInfo, but without any succes.

```
    $inv = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture<br>
    $fmtDate = "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
    
    $DateRequest = ([datetime]::ParseExact(($($_."Date Request")),$fmtDate,$inv).ToString($fmtDate))
```

**Does anyone hove any suggestions to solve this?**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the dates in your CSV file have this format `d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss` (`yyyy` is in lowercase and the days and months in the fields do not have a leading zeroes).

Try

```
$fmtDate = "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

What puzzles me is why you want to first parse the date in the csv and then use `ToString()` to reformat it in the exact same string format.

Take off the `.ToString($fmtDate)` as in

```
$DateRequest = [datetime]::ParseExact($_."Date Request",$fmtDate, $inv)
```

and feed that DateTime object into the Excel cell

Answer (score 1):

`dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss` does NOT describe the input date format you have - `dd` and `MM` are for day and month numbers **with leading zeros**.

Use:

```
$fmtDateInput = 'd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$fmtDateOutput = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

[datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, $fmtDateInput, $culture).ToString($fmtDateOutput)
```

Comment: I think i solved it. When i removed the **ToString** i got a good result

Comment: @koen my bad, there was a typo in the `$fmtDateOutput` string